# How to make something an odd multiple 3

Tags: java

I am trying to have something be printed out when only the user does not enter a size of an odd multiple of 3. For example, an error is printed when the number is not a multiple of 3 and not odd. Here is my code so far:

```
if (height % 3 != 0 && height % 2 != 1) {
    errorFlag(grid);
}
```

How can I make it so that if the user does not enter an odd multiple of 3 then my "errorFlag" is printed?

Thanks

Comment: Change `&&` to `||`.

Comment: `if (!(height%3==0 && height%2==1)) { errorFlag(grid); }` would work. It translates directly from what you would expect in English. Don't prematurely optimize if you can express what you want in a more readable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `&&` to an `||` and it should work:

```
if (height%3 != 0 || height%2 != 1) {
        errorFlag(grid);
}
```

For further confirmation, I just tested that exact code with 12 pseudo-random numbers --adding console output statements-- and this is what I got:

```
3 is bad
4 is good
5 is good
6 is good
33 is bad
27 is bad
56 is good
24 is good
15 is bad
45 is bad
46 is good
78 is good
```

Looks like it was already answered in the comments. @shmosel